# Google Places API - Using multiple place types from a checkbox

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

UPDATED:
I am trying to send a google places API request with multiple types as an array. However, I am not able to pass an array variable with the list of places added from checkbox values. Any help would be highly appreciated.

This works:

```
var poi = new google.maps.LatLng(lt,lg);
var gplaces = ['shopping_mall','bus_station'];

var request = {
    location: poi,
    radius: '500',
    types: gplaces
  };
```

But not this:

```
var poi = new google.maps.LatLng(lt,lg);
var gplaces = []

$('#chklist:checked').each(function() {
   gplaces.push($(this).val());
 });

var request = {
    location: poi,
    radius: '500',
    types: gplaces
  };
```

In the second case, the API would return a default list of places(as if I did not pass any types at all).

I tried a console.log(gplaces) and it contains ['shopping_mall','bus_station'].

I also checked console.log(request) and I could see the individual elements of the list in the request.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Can you paste more code? It work fine for me

Comment: @weigreen I've updated the question now. Please check.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I tried both of your code, and it works for me. Maybe the issue is not there. Try to check it again for you to confirm where the error is.

Here is the sample that I test.

```
infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
var gplaces = ['shopping_mall','bus_station']
service.nearbySearch({
location: pyrmont,
radius: '500',
types: gplaces
}, callback);
```

and here they are both working.

```
infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.nearbySearch({
location: pyrmont,
radius: 500,
types: ['shopping_mall','bus_station']
}, callback);
```

Also for additional information, the `types` parameter is deprecated as of February 16, 2016, replaced by a new type parameter which only supports one `type` per search request. (However, these types may still be returned in the results of a search). Requests using the deprecated features will be supported until **February 16, 2017**, after which all text searches must use the new implementation.

Just be reminded for this [deprecation announcement](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places).

Comment: Sorry, you are right. Passing an array variable indeed works fine. However, in my case, the array (`gplaces`) gets values from checkboxes. I have updated the question now. Please see it again.